# The perimeter of a rectangular field that is twice as long as it is wide is $450$ yards. What are the field's dimensions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rectangular field is twice as long as it is wide. If the perimeter of the field is 450 yards, what are the field's dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ denote width. $$2x +2(2x)=450$$ Solving leads to $$x=75 \ \text{yards}$$ Now the length is just twice that. In future you should show your attempts as it makes people feel more charitable.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic approach.**  Let the width be denoted $w$.  Then the length is twice the width, which can be expressed as $\underline{\qquad}$.  The perimeter is twice the width plus twice the length, and is therefore $\underline{\qquad}$.  Letting that equal $450$ yards, we can solve for $w$, the width, and then the length is simply twice that.